# Is there code to generate the statevector amplitude histogram for a circuit outside the Composer?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

When using the IBM Composer, in the bottom left of our screen we have access to two histograms.  A theoretical probability histogram and a statevector amplitude histogram.  I'm looking for ways to create these same visualizations outside of the Composer (So in the Lab or other Jupyter Notebook).  I know that for an experimental probability histogram I can measure my qubits using an ideal simulator like the `'aer_simulator'` and then use `plot_histogram`, but I have not found anything that would portray the statevector amplitude histogram.

I assume there is code to generate this, and I'm not asking for anything that has not been released or involves proprietary information, but for it to be a part of their constant visualization, I simply assumed there was code to generate it, but I cannot seem to find it!  Thank you for your guidance!

To see which visualization I am referring to scroll down to the Statevector View section of [this](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iqx/visualizations) link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qiskit, there are two easy ways to get the state vector of a quantum circuit.

The easiest is just

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
Statevector(mycircuit)
```

This does not create a histogram of results, but actually keep track of the state vector.

You can also use a simulator, with I think is faster for larger programs.

```
def get_statevector(circuit):
    sim = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
    circuit.save_statevector()
    result = execute(circuit, sim).result()
    return result.get_statevector()
```

The simulator keeps track and dumps the actual statevector, not a histogram.

Comment: This is what I ended up using in the end as an equivilent form.  Thanks! @Frank Yellin